# How to add custom message to certain products on both checkout and product page?

Tags: product, checkout, product-attribute, product-view

I'm trying to create a custom message appear for certain products that are flagged as so from the admin panel. These products will create a message on both the checkout and product page. For example some products will have to give an alert saying "This product does not give free shipping." in a red box.

I've attempted to create a module for this with an event handler however I can't seem to figure it out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have any code that you can upload so we can help? Otherwise there are plenty of blog posts out there on creating magento modules such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento